# Howto call FirebaseAuth.signInWithCustomToken in Java

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Using Firebase's Java SDK, I'm able to [Create Custom Tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens).

But in order to [Verify an ID Token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens), I first need to `signInWithCustomToken` using the Web or Android API.

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/custom-auth

Isn't there  away to call `signInWithCustomToken` while still in the same Java runtime? This [source file](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-java/blob/master/src/test/java/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuthIT.java#L619-L634) indicates that there used to be a way to do this. But said function no longer exists in the latest version (`com.google.firebase/firebase-admin "6.11.0"`).

So the first line works in Java. But the second line fails with the given error.

```
// Works in Java
String token FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createCustomToken("some-uid")

// Fails in Java; only see docs for this, in Android
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithCustomToken(token)

IllegalArgumentException No matching method found: signInWithCustomToken for class com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth  clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod (Reflector.java:53)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "while still in the same Java runtime"? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @DougStevenson I've updated the question to be clearer. The second line doesn't work. And I only see docs for this, for Android.

Comment: It's still not clear to me what problem you're trying to solve, but the sum of it is that you can't sign in a user on a backend using the Admin SDK.

Comment: @DougStevenson Hmm, that makes development difficult. Happy we're moving away from Firebase, lol. But ok, that answers my question.

Comment: What exactly is difficult? I still don't understand why a signin is needed on the backend.  Firebase is focused on providing serverless backend infrastructure to be consumed in web and mobile apps.

Comment: @DougStevenson, I'd like to unit test my backend security interceptors which expect id tokens with custom claims.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't sign in a user using the Admin SDK on a backend.  Signing in can only be done in the client app, which gives it a token to use for the interactions between the app and backend services.